# Most of my water simulation scene disappears when viewed through the camera

Tags: camera

I created this water simulation animation and I'm ready to render it. when I tried to set up the camera most of the scene disappears. I tried deleting the original camera and adding a new camera but the same problem happened. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

John

[image: Animation screenshot no camera]

[image: Animation screenshot through camera view]

Answer (score 0):

It is almost as if your camera is clipping. Maybe your scene is so large as to exceed the default 1000m end clip? Go to the Camera Object Properties and change the Clip End to suit your scene better. Here is an example of camera end clipping.

Not in camera view:

[image]

Same scene in camera view:

[image]